# How to write a custom pooling layer module in tensor flow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have thought that adding a new module which will do the center pooling.

I was looking in the tensorflow code and there is a file named `gen_nn_ops.py` which internally calls function from another file by passing "Maxpool", "AvgPool", etc. parameters to do the required computation.

I want to do centre pooling which selects the center element in the window. I have code ready for the matlab and c++ versions but need to know how to add a new module in TensorFlow for such computation. Also where to set the backpropogation code.

Answer (score 9):

A custom pooling layer would probably be implemented in C++. To see what you'd need to do, let's see where the implementation of [`tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#max_pool_with_argmax) lives:

1. The Python wrapper function (`tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax()` itself) is automatically generated, in `gen_nn_ops.py`. This is ultimately imported into [`nn.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/75937824b9834b04c9a371447da27f322dfd9882/tensorflow/python/ops/nn.py), so that it appears under `tf.nn` when you `import tensorflow as tf`.
2. In C++, there is an [op registration in `ops/nn_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0c06d8d9aa88b0596b734c8feb6435d2cf359b7e/tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc#L356), and a [kernel registration in `kernels/maxpooling_op.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0c06d8d9aa88b0596b734c8feb6435d2cf359b7e/tensorflow/core/kernels/maxpooling_op.cc#L527).
3. The [kernel itself is defined in `kernels/maxpooling_op.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0c06d8d9aa88b0596b734c8feb6435d2cf359b7e/tensorflow/core/kernels/maxpooling_op.cc#L393).
4. The gradient is defined as a separate op—`"MaxPoolWithArgmaxGrad"`—in the same places.

There's a fair amount of work to do to add a new op (see [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) for a more complete guide), but hopefully these pointers can help!

Comment: The "this tutorial" link is broken (again). The correct URL is https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op