# How to create a custom pooling function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently tensor flow provides built-in function to max pooling. I want to customize it. Instead of choosing the max value from the feature vector, I want to get the value by adding all the values of feature vector. For this matter I have to create a custom function. I have come across a solution that you have to define the op in C++ and then use it in python. But is there an easier way to implement it directly in python? And I know this question was asked before on Stack overflow but I couldn't understand the solution to it.

Comment: Was this the previous answer you were referring to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298823/how-to-write-a-custom-pooling-layer-module-in-tensor-flow If not, that has a good description of what to do.